# Insert HTML Table inside Ext.data.TreeStore node EXT JS 4x

Tags: extjs, html-table

Please help me to find the solution to insert html table inside node of treepanel ext js.

Find the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but maybe it can be done with Ext.tree.View and either tpl or itemTpl

Comment: Can you please post a sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/arunv/kGksk/

It should help you get started.

extjs:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: "alegrbra", leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: '<table class="sample_table"><tr><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>21</td><td>22</td></tr></table>', leaf: true }
        ]
    }
});

var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    useArrows: true,
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

var root = tree.getRootNode();
root.appendChild({ text: '<table class="sample_table"><tr><td>aa</td><td>ab</td></tr><tr><td>ba</td><td>bb</td></tr></table>', leaf: true});
```

css:

```
.sample_table {
    display: inline-block;
}

.sample_table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arun, Is any other way using tpl or itemTpl

Comment: I don't know of anything out of the box for using templates with trees. You could try using Ext.Template: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.Template

Comment: Actually you might be able to use itemTpl on the TreeView in the TreePanel